# React router & serverside rending

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I'm currently having a weird problem with server-side rendering using react / react-router which I simply can't figure out. I'm using ES6 with Babel (6to5) for transpiling

Server.js snippet

```
import routes2 from '../jsx/routes.js';
var routes = React.createElement(Router.Route, { handler: APP, path: "/" });

Router.run(routes, '/', (Handler) => {
    const CONTENT = React.renderToString(<Handler/>);
    console.log('\r\nroutes')
    console.log(CONTENT)
})

Router.run(routes2, '/', (Handler) => {
    const CONTENT2 = React.renderToString(<Handler/>);
    console.log('\r\nroutes2')
    console.log(CONTENT2)
})
```

Routes.js

```
"use strict";

var _interopRequire = function (obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj["default"] : obj; };

var APP = _interopRequire(require("./app.js"));

var React = _interopRequire(require("react"));

var Router = _interopRequire(require("react-router"));

module.exports = React.createElement(Router.Route, { handler: APP, path: "/" });
```

Output

CONTENT correctly outputs my rendered component

CONTENT2 outputs `<noscript></noscript>`

For some reason when I import my routes from an external file (so I can require them in both my client and server code) my serverside rendering fails to output the correct HTML

Comment: I have no idea what I've done which has fixed it but my code is now working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out what I changed to make things work. I had gotten my APP import wrong in my original Routes.js file (pre transpile)

I was using

```
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'react-router';
import APP from './app.js';

export default (
    <Router.Route handler={APP} path="/"/>
)
```

instead of

```
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'react-router';
import { APP } from './app.js';

export default (
    <Router.Route handler={APP} path="/"/>
)
```